# Melhor jeito de tratar string em nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com uso de um socket para uma aplicação no meu servidor.
Estou tendo dificuldades para tratar as chamadas geradas pelo módulo net.

A minha aplicação é em tempo real, ou seja, a cada 200ms mando uma requisição para o socket para que ele possa me retornar algumas informações, porém às vezes se faz necessário fazer outras chamadas e assim minha vida fica complicada para tratar essas strings de resposta.

O que estou fazendo agora é tratando a string com a função "split" do javascript, porém gostaria de saber se existe um jeito mais intuitivo de fazer isso.

Segue o código:

```
mvcp.on("data", function(chunk) {
//console.log(chunk)
split_tempos = "";
index = "";
total_index = "";
allchunk = chunk;
str = allchunk.toString();

//pra verificar se é um list ou um usta
split_verify = str.split('\n');
if(!parseInt(split_verify[1])){
    if (!(str.indexOf("202 OK") > -1) && !(str.indexOf("201 OK") > -1)) {
        split_todos = str.split(" ");
        split_nome = str.split("\"");
        split_dados = split_nome[2];
        split_playlist_info = split_nome[4];
        if (typeof split_dados != 'undefined' && split_playlist_info != '' && typeof split_playlist_info != 'undefined') 
        {

            split_playlist_info = split_playlist_info.split(" ");
            index = split_playlist_info[7];
            if(typeof index != 'undefined'){
                if (typeof split_dados != 'undefined'){
                    index = index.split('\r');
                    index = index[0];
                    index_global = index;
                }
            }               
            total_pl = split_playlist_info[6];
        }
        if (typeof split_dados != 'undefined') {
            split_tempos = split_dados.split(" ");

        }
        var JSONresponse = {};
        JSONresponse.data = [];
        var nome = split_nome[1];
        var tamanho;
        if(typeof nome != 'undefined'){
            nome = nome.split("/");
            tamanho = nome.length - 1;
        }else
        {
            nome = "";
        }
        console.log(nome);
        JSONresponse.data.push({
            status: split_todos[1],
            filename: split_nome[1],
            nome:nome[tamanho],
            position: split_tempos[1],
            fps:split_tempos[3],
            inpoint:split_tempos[4],
            outpoint:split_tempos[5],
            length:split_tempos[6],
            b_filename: split_todos[3]
        });
        str = JSON.stringify(JSONresponse);
        io.sockets.emit("incomingMessage", str);
    }

}else
{
    list = str.split('\n');

    var dados = [];
    for(i = 2; i < (list.length -2); i++)
    {
        var dados_completos = "";
        var dados_movie = "";
        var pl_item = list[i].split("\"");

        var index = pl_item[0];
        var nome = pl_item[1];
        dados_completos = pl_item[2];
        if(typeof dados_completos != 'undefined'){
            dados_movie = dados_completos.split(' ');
            inpoint = dados_movie[3];
            outpoint = dados_movie[4];
            real_length = dados_movie[5];
            calculated_length = dados_movie[6];
        }

        var data = {index: index,index_current: index_global, nome: nome, inpoint: inpoint, outpoint: outpoint, real_length: real_length, calculated_length: calculated_length};

        dados.push(data);

    }

    io.sockets.emit("list", dados);


}
```

});

Comment: @Sergio editei com o código.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta.